# jQuery IF Formula with Multiple Conditions & Number Range

Tags: jquery, if-statement, numbers, range

I need to set several `if` statements using jquery:

if `amt` (variable) is between 0 to 5000 change input value

else if `amt` is between `5001` to `17999` change input value

else change input value

My else if doesn't seem to work and I always end-up with the else return.

my input type is set to number.

```
$('#pledge').submit(function() {
  var amt = $("#donation").val();
  if ((amt <= '17999' && amt >= '5001')) {
    $('#priority').val('2');
  } else if (amt <= '0' && amt >= '5000') {
    $('#priority').val('2');
  } else {
    $('#priority').val('3');
  }
});
```

It always returns priority = 3.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debugger before the if statement and validating `amt` is what you think it is? Also, you may try to convert `amt` to an integer and change all the string values to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare with strings, compare with numbers. When you compare strings, they're compared character by character, so `'10' < '9'` because `'1' < '9'`.

You also have the comparison operators backwards in the `else if`.

```
$('#pledge').submit(function() {
  var amt = parseInt($("#donation").val(), 10);
  if (amt <= 17999 && amt >= 5001) {
    $('#priority').val('2');
  } else if (amt >= 0 && amt < 5000) {
    $('#priority').val('2');
  } else {
    $('#priority').val('3');
  }
});
```

Comment: So if the amt is a string only containing integers, how to I avoid the character by character comparisons? I managed with PHP and I am not getting this issue.            
`if ($amount <= 5000) {
    $priority="1";} 
    else if($amount >= 5001 && $amount <= 17999) {$priority="2";}
    else {$priority="3";}` Will a later get a bug on this?

Comment: JavaScript is different from PHP in this regard. PHP converts numerical strings to numbers when they're compared, so `"9" < "10"` is the same as `9 < 10`. JavaScript only converts a numerical string to a number if you're comparing it to a number, not when comparing to another string. `"9" < 10` and `9 < "10"` but not `"9" < "10"`.